# Responsive scrolling x&y (horizontal for desktop, vertical for mobile)...how?

Tags: jquery, scroll, responsive-design, scrollbar

I've been fighting this for a while now and it's driving me crazy. I've tried a multitude of different custom jQuery scollbars that support horizontal mousewheel scroll but every time I try to implement a switch of the scrolling direction it ends up usually breaking.

For example, greater than 960px will scroll horizontal with content set to nowrap.
Less than 960 will scroll vertical for the mobile responsive design.

How can I do this and if so, is it also possible to have a custom scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

With [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) you can define custom css for different resolutions.

Comment: After importing Bootstrap into your page it is the matter of css to set overflows correctly.

Comment: It's not a matter of the CSS and page structure, the issue is the jQuery and the fact I'm trying to set the scroll direction based on window width. I havent come across a jQuery plugin that can easily switch the direction of mousewheel scroll. From what I've seen it's either X or Y only.